# Google Map Coordinates difference for Satellite and Map

Tags: google-maps

OK,

In short. google map pointing two different location of a same coordinates (39.91664, 116.39079).

see the link:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=39.91664,+116.39079&aq=&sll=22.396428,114.109497&sspn=0.679282,1.279907&ie=UTF8&ll=39.917965,116.393323&spn=0.008805,0.019999&z=16

In Satellite mode it points correctly on the Forbidden City of Beijing.

However in map view, it pointed to a bit west of it.

Can anybody tell me why and how to resolve the real position of a coordinate? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The alignment error is a fault on Google's part, so it's not something you can determine without their help. That said, you can usually assume the image view is in error, as the maps would have been made by professional cartographers.  The images are combined from multiple sources from many heights and angles, and usually have many small alignment errors.

You may want to report it in their support forum, which has a category for the map data - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

because the evil government forbid every map provider to add offset to map data.  so the satellite is accurate, and map is not correct,and different type of maps has different type of offset.